# Find the matrix of $f$ in the ordered basis {$E^{11}$, $E^{12}$, $E^{13}$, $E^{21}$, $E^{22}$, $E^{23}$}

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be the space of all $2\times3$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $f$ be the bilinear form on $V$ defined by $f(X,Y)={\rm tr}(X^tAY)$, where $$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find the matrix of $f$ in the ordered basis {$E^{11}$, $E^{12}$, $E^{13}$, $E^{21}$, $E^{22}$, $E^{23}$} where $E^{ij}$ is the matrix whose only non-zero entry is a 1 in row i and column j.

Do I have to evaluate $L(E^{ij})$?

Comment: What is $L$? ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the basis elements to $\beta = \{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_6\}$. Then the matrix of the bilinear form $f$ relative to the basis $\beta$ is the matrix $[f]_{\beta}$, whose $ij$ entry is $f(\xi_i,\xi_j)$. 
So computing this for all $i,j \in \{1, \dots, 6\}$, will give the desired $6 \times 6$ matrix with entries in $\Bbb{R}$.